# Continuum Limit of Lattice QCD

Tags: lattice-gauge-theory

I was trying to verify that the continuum limit of lattice QCD is indeed, regular old QCD, but I ran into an issue where when I tried to take the limit $a \rightarrow 0$ ($a$ is the lattice spacing), I ended up with a Hamiltonian that didn't even depend on the gluon fields anymore. Are there subtleties associated with taking this continuum limit that aren't present for the free Dirac theory? In 1+1 spacetime dimensions, where the space is discretized but time remains continuous, I will define $N$ sites in 1-D space, labeled from $1$ to $N$, and links labelled $12, 23,..., N1$. I can construct a Hamiltonian (following Kogut & Stephanov, *The Phases of Quantum Chromodynamics: From Confinement To Extreme Environments*, ch.6) for lattice QCD by defining quark fields on all the sites and gluon fields on all the links. The gamma matrices I use are $\gamma^0 = \sigma_1$, $\gamma^1 = i\sigma_2$. Then, in the $A_0=0$ gauge, the Hamiltonian (ignoring the kinetic term for the gluon fields) looks like

$$H = \begin{pmatrix}\bar{\psi}(1) &\bar{\psi}(2) & \cdots & \bar{\psi}(N) \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}m+\frac{i\gamma^1}{a} & -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}U(12) & 0 & \cdots & -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}U^{-1}(N1) \\ -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}U^{-1}(12) & m+\frac{i\gamma^1}{a} & -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}U(23) & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}U^{-1}(23) & m + \frac{i\gamma^1}{a} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}U(N1) & 0 & 0 & \cdots & m + \frac{i\gamma^1}{a} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\psi(1)\\ \psi(2) \\ \vdots \\ \psi(N) \end{pmatrix}$$

where $U(jk) = \exp(\frac{i}{2}agA^1_a(jk)\lambda^a)$, and $\lambda^a$ are the eight Gell-Mann matrices.

It is very easy to see that in the limit $a \rightarrow 0$, if I ``turn off'' the gauge fields ($A_1 = 0$) then I very easily recover

$$H = \int dx \bar{\psi}(x)[-i\gamma^1 \partial_1 + m]\psi(x)$$

which is the Hamiltonian for the free Dirac theory. The problem arises when I try to take the continuum limit in the presence of the gluon fields. In the limit $a \rightarrow 0$, $U(jk) \approx 1+\frac{i}{2}agA_a^1(jk)\lambda^a$ and so I end up with a Hamiltonian like

$$\approx \begin{pmatrix}\bar{\psi}(1) &\bar{\psi}(2) & \cdots & \bar{\psi}(N) \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}m+\frac{i\gamma^1}{a} & -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}(1+ {\frac{i}{2}agA^1_a(12)\lambda^a}) & 0 & \cdots & -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}(1- {\frac{i}{2}agA^1_a(N1)\lambda^a}) \\ -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}(1- {\frac{i}{2}agA^1_a(12)\lambda^a}) & m+\frac{i\gamma^1}{a} & -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}(1+ {\frac{i}{2}agA^1_a(23)\lambda^a}) & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}(1- {\frac{i}{2}agA^1_a(23)\lambda^a}) & m + \frac{i\gamma^1}{a} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\-\frac{i\gamma^1}{a}(1+ {\frac{i}{2}agA^1_a(N1)\lambda^a}) & 0 & 0 & \cdots & m + \frac{i\gamma^1}{a} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\psi(1)\\ \psi(2) \\ \vdots \\ \psi(N) \end{pmatrix}$$

In the continuum limit $a \rightarrow 0$, why don't terms in the matrix multiplication like $\bar{\psi}(1){\frac{i}{2}agA^a_1(12)\lambda^a}\psi(2)$ and $-\bar{\psi}(2){\frac{i}{2}agA^1_a(12)\lambda^a}\psi(1)$ cancel? I should hope that they don't, so that I can obtain the following in the continuum limit:

$$H = \int dx \bar{\psi}(x)[-i\gamma^1 \partial_1 -g\gamma^1 A_1 + m]\psi(x)$$